# Delphi program generating incorrect CRC16, want to replicate behavior in C#

Tags: c#, delphi, dll, crc

I've inherited a Delphi application which I need to convert to a C# application at my job.

One part uses what is supposed to be a CRC16 function in an external dll to create a checksum for some data. The problem is that this CRC which gets generated doesn't match any of the CRCs ive managed to generate elsewhere.

I've tried about 10 different CRC code snippets which I found online, and have tried several online generators. The CRCs I generate match the ones I generate online, for example at -

http://www.lammertbies.nl/comm/info/crc-calculation.html

So my only conclusion now is that the Delphi application is not generating a valid CRC16 checksum. This leaves me with two options

1] Try to figure out which kind of CRC it is generating

2] Somehow call the functions in the DLL from inside C#

I've tried both and failed miserably.

--

All the source is on github -

https://github.com/delphi2sharp/delphisharp/blob/master/CRC16Test/CRC16Test/Program.cs

https://github.com/delphi2sharp/delphisharp/blob/master/DelphiCRC16Test/Unit1.pas

and the CRC.DLL is also there too.

--

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Do we know what version of Delphi we're talking about ? If I understand things correctly, Delphi didn't get full Unicode support until 2009; although that difference is independent on the nature of the data that you're attempting to CRC...

Comment: The registration details never include characters other than A-Z, 1-9. So it's not a concern.

Comment: I just noticed this forum post on MSDN; it has particular relevance to objects that return a delphi string, which is a possibility here. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/d9296998-9729-45c3-89e9-577c618e4cbe/

Comment: Actually that is a concern; depending on the encoding specified, in .net they'll be either 16 or 32bit, and that will make a difference to the CRC.

Comment: I do wish the downvoters would comment as to why they downvoted especially on a question with answers and comments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you need a 2 phase approach.

1./ For the moment write an "unsafe/pInvoke" wrapper and call the native dll.

2./ Once the Delphi app is replaced and you control the encoding as well as the decoding, write a more standard CRC function.

Calling a native DLL is not that difficult, have a look at some of the examples at pinvoke.net.

Comment: That's certainly true - but my fear is that here we're fixing the symptom and not the cause; if this CRC dll is calculating in a non-standard way then you have no guarantee of how it might cause a collision in the future.

Comment: Check out the response to your answer, I have addressed those concerns. If I can get this going using Pinvoke i'll be happy.

Comment: Indeed; the plot thickens!  If you're happy to swallow those concerns then Tim and Shaun are absolutely correct P/Invoke is the way to go.

Comment: I agree with Tim, a two phase approach as the way to go and try to get rid of the poor implementation. I had a similar scenario with an poorly implemented encryption algorithm but in that scenario I had to dis-assemble the x86 assembly and re-implement in C#; not an approach I would recommend if it can be avoided.

Answer (score 3):

If you need backward compatibility why don't you use a pInvoke wrapper of the original native dll.

Comment: Your DLL exposes 3 methods CRC_16, CRC_32 and CRC_CCITT as for the actual syntax of the pinvoke wrapper I could guess but I don't know what CRC_MAKE is (or if there is some implicit casting happening). What is in CRC.INC?

Comment: CRC.INC defines the calls to CRC.DLL. Don't ask me how it works, Delphi is new to me. CRC_MAKE is defined at the top of CRC.INC, you just need to pass 0 for that one.

Comment: Ah - I didn't notice the extra files in GitHub - as you can see from the .INC files - the pascal declaration should be able to act as a guide to your pInvoke [DllImport "CRC.DLL", EntryPoint="CRC_16" CharSet=CharSet.Auto, SetLastError=true]
public extern static void CRC_16(byte[], int, byte);

Comment: You may need to play with the charset value

Comment: Keep getting 'Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.'.

Comment: Maybe it is reading beyond the length of the buffer - is it NULL terminated?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I apologise for posting this as an answer; it's just too unwieldy to put into a comment.

Do you not have the source to CRC.Dll then ?

Looking at it, it *looks* like another Delphi based file, which has a reliance on atleast Kernel32.dll; other then that I can't say on this Mac.
An observation is that this difference may be due to Unicode differences between Delphi and .Net.

If you're porting this to .Net though, is there any reason why you can't just replace that CRC with a known good solution or do you have to retain some backwards compatibility ?
If so; can you not use the common CRC code in .Net and do a batch update on the legacy stuff?

If not; then perhaps the answer is to dump this bespoke CRC generator and use something that validates your expectations and provides repeatable accurate results.

Comment: Is the data Text, XML, Binary or something else ?

Comment: Backwards compatability is essential. We have a database full of serial keys for our application which is deployed on hundreds of computers across the country. By performing bitwise operations on the serial we are able to see which features of our application are enabled for the customer. It would be very simple, BUT, before we can do perform those bitwise operations we need to DES decode the serial, and in order to do that we need to get the CRC16 checksum of several of the user's registration details and use them as the decoding key.

Comment: In saying that, we're overhauling our registration system in the next 6 months and going with an online validation type of approach. When we do this, I will certainly not be using the same CRC routine. But for legacy clients (a lot of them will never be moved to the new system because they'll simply refuse) they will continue using the old system.

Comment: In which case; a safe refactor and batch update might be the sanest option; Because of marshalling differences and your inability to know why this CRC dll isn't creating a standard result; there's no way of knowing if your instantiating this DLL through C# platform invoke is returning the correct result or not.

Comment: ... as Russ suggests but perhaps with an extra column for the new CRC - even looking at mass data your eye may see what commonsense does not i.e. a common pattern between the 2 numbers that may help identify where the original CRC implementation was badly implemented - then you can add that "mistake" to your good implementation and voila you have a BadlyImplementedCRC method in C#